# Delphi - ComboBox - Click event handler running when key is pressed

Tags: delphi, combobox, onclick, onkeypress

I'm using Delphi where I have a ComboBox on a form - in the Click event handler I'm calling ShowMessage('click') while in the KeyPress event handler ShowMessage('KeyPress'). When the ComboBox has the focus, and I press a 'normal' key like 'd', first the KeyPress event handler is running then follows the Click event handler.

Interesting: when the combobox's style property is set to csDropDownList or csDropDown, the Click event handler runs even twice, when it's set to csSimple, it runs 'only' once.

So I can't easily have a combobox where i (in the click event handler) set the focus to the next component after the user selected an item by clicking, since when the user is pressing keys the click event handler will run and set the focus to the next component. so what i planned for usability purposes would drive him crazy.

I wished the Delphi developers would be forced to use such a program for a whole week, 8 hours a day - I'd set the forms caption to sth like 'Never ever trigger the click event handler when the mouse wasn't really clicked!' - Though the problem is well known FOR MANY YEARS now, and Delphi costs REALLY much, the problems still exists.

Is there anyone with a good solution?

Comment: `TCustomCombo` fires `OnClick` before `OnSelect` in response to item selection changes and key presses. There is really nothing you can do about that without altering the VCL's source code, or subclassing the ComboBox to handle `CBN_SELCHANGE` and `WM_CHAR` messages directly. But, what you can do is don't change focus in `OnClick` or `OnSelect` if it is immediately preceded by an `OnKey...` event.

Comment: Why are you relying on `OnClick` and `OnKeyPress` events? Wouldn't it be better to make use of `OnChange` which occurs when the user changes the text displayed in the edit region, `OnCloseUp` which occurs when the drop-down list closes up due to some user action and/or `OnSelect` which occurs when the user selects a string in the drop-down list? Also why are you moving focus to next control after user made certain selection. What if user made wrong choice? Since you already moved focus to another control you made user correcting his error a lot harder.

Comment: @SilverWarior - Thank you. Well, since none of the events you mentioned is -reliably- telling me, whether the user has made his choice, i do not rely on them.

OnSelect is fired whenever the user presses a key and the selection changes, no matter he has finished or not.
OnChange is never fired, since my ComboBox.Style is set to csDropDownList, and the Edit Component is disabled.
OnCloseUp is fired when the DropDownList is closed up, no matter the user clicked on the little arrow beside the component or he clicked on an item.

I keep relying on Keys tab, enter, esc and a click on an item.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Thanks for your time, regard it as not wasted. My Workaround: Local Var 'FakeClickEvent' init to False. In KeyDown Event Handler i set it to True. Click Event Handler will run normally only if it is False. In KeyUp Event Handler i set it back to False.

Comment: You could check `DroppedDown` property in `OnSelect` event to see whether selection was made while DropDown list was shown or after the DropDown list was closed.

Comment: @SilverWarior - Unfortunately the DroppedDown property doesn't reliably saying anything about whether the user has made his choice or not. If I press keys it's always 1, if I use the mouse, it's always 0. And I don't want to change the AutoXY props of the combo. My work around mentioned above works fine, but nevertheless I thank you for your help.